# Unknown field in msi log output

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I was wondering what the (A4:68) field means and if it can be used to help debug code.

MSI (s) (A4:68) [09:44:03:998]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=AttachDB,,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked blog explains very clearly how to interpret MSI logs:

- [How to Interpret Windows Installer Logs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx)

As the article states the `(A4:68)` are the process ID and thread ID, respectively.